# copying discrete events from one dataframe to another by comparing timestamps

Tags: python, timestamp

I have a pandas dataframe A with 10 minute time series of machine production. I have also got another dataframe B of different length with discrete downtime events (for eg. system maintenance) provided with a start time and end time (not a 10 minute series). I would like to transfer the downtime reasons to the 10 minute time series. For this I have filled in the missing 10 minute timestamps in the dataframe A. I would now like to compare each 10 minute timestamp from dataframe A and copy the downtime reason from B if it falls within the start time and end time or just leave it with an NA if it does not. How do I do this? I have found similar questions and tried many ways but could not succeed. Any suggestions would be highly appreciated. Thank you.

[Dataframe A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/roaqM.png)
[Dataframe B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5kTuK.png)

Comment: add few code you tried

Comment: Is it possible to give some sample data (together with expected output)?

Comment: @Willem: Thanks for your reply. I have updated the question with the dataframe pictures. In this case my expectation is to have NA in a new column in dataframe A since the timestamps are not within the starttime and endtime in dataframe B. Ofcourse the new column in A should have the exact downtime reason if the values fall within the starttime and endtime in dataframe B.